# Symfony 2 save ManyToMany Unidirectional Association

Tags: forms, symfony, save, roles

I have 3 entities:

User (based on fosuserbundle)

Group

Groups (virtual to get all group)

Role

When I generate form everything works fine:

GroupsType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('groups', 'collection', array('type' => new GroupType($this->ExistingRoles)))
        ;
}
```

GroupType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('groupRoles', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Role',
        'property' => 'role',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'property' => 'name',
        'required' => false,
        'by_reference' => true,
        ))
    ;
}
```

And I have form with All Groups and checkbox checked for each group.

But Now I want save/update this.

My list of manytomany group_id to role_id I defined in Group entity:

```
/**
 * GROUP ManyToMany with ROLE Unidirectional Association
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role",inversedBy="group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="group_roles")
 */
protected $groupRoles;
```

and in Role entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", mappedBy="groupRoles")
 */
private $group;
```

I tried something like this but doesn't work:

```
$all = $form->getData();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
foreach($all as $d){
    $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Group')->find($d->getId());
    $em->persist($d);
    $em->flush();
}
```

How to save form like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

need to change controller save

```
        $all = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        foreach($all as $d){
            $em->persist($d);
        }
        $em->flush();
```

and in group Entity:

```
public function setgroupRoles($roles)
{
    $this->groupRoles = $roles;


    return $this;
}
```

in Role Entity

```
/**
 * Add group
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Group $group
 * @return Role
 */
public function addGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\Group $group)
{
    $this->group[] = $group;
    $group->groupRoles($group);
    return $this;
}
```

In GroupType by_reference to false

Now work all perfect :)